# Are the Agents sentinels or just software programs?

Tags: movie, the-matrix

In the first film, Agent Smith could give the sentinels orders. Is there more to this connection or not?

Comment: Are you asking whether they had mechanical counterparts outside the Matrix?

Comment: I was wondering if they have mechanical bodies outside of the Matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Morpheus tells <s>us</s> Neo that the Agents are...

> ***...Sentient programs. They can move in and out of any software still
> hardwired to the system.** That means that anyone we haven't
> unplugged...is potentially an Agent. Inside the Matrix, they are
> everyone...and they are no one.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Matrix: Transcript](https://sfy.ru/transcript/matrix_ts)</sup></sub>

Based on this we can reasonably assume that they have no specific *physical* form outside the Matrix, simply moving from body to body within the Matrix.

---

Smith certainly seems to have a level of authority over the Sentinels (in the scene you've mentioned) but given that they're treated as largely disposable shock-troops, that's not saying much.